# Updating data from HTML text fields to MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I try to update data from HTML text fields to database using PHP. I would like to update notifications field. I cannot get text field values to SQL query. Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); // Run query
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> 
        <tr><td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>      
        <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="notifications" value="<?php echo $row[5];?>" size=13></td></tr>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['save'])) { 
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) // For loop
    {
        $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id"); // Get id from query
        $notifications = $_POST['notifications'];
        $update = "UPDATE testtable SET notifications = {$notifications[$i]} WHERE id = {$id}";
        echo "$update<br>";
        //mysql_query($update); // Run
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the noticifations field is likely a string, so you need to escape it with quotes like this:

`$update = "UPDATE testtable SET notifications = '{$notifications[$i]}' WHERE id = {$id}";`

Your code is quite open to injection attacks, you should use prepared statements and move to PDO or msqli though to ward off potential attacks.

Comment: Problem solved. I just added [] to input type name and now it works.